# How to solve a Second order and Second Degree Differential Equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I have came across a second order as well as second degree differential equation in study of cosmic inflation. The full equations is quite messy so let me give a prototype:
        $$A(x) y''(x)^2 + B(x) y(x) + C(x) = 0 $$ $$y'(0) = a$$ $$y(0) = b$$
What I usually do in this type of cases is to ask Mathematica to solve it. And she usually solve it. But, sometimes mathematica show some error, for instance "singularity or stiffness at x=d". Now, I am trying to solve them numerically in some basic language ( read python ). But, the way we solve 2nd order differential equation is not applicable here, i.e., writing it as two first order differential equations.

*Can any one provide me with an algorithm for solving the problem numerically and/or direct me to the literature where I can learn more about the methods*.

Thanks in advance.

N.B. I have asked this question in stackoverflow, now asking here as suggested in a helpful comment.

Comment: If you are just interested in the methods required for physics, you can check out the textbook 'Mathematical methods for Physicists and Engineers' by K.F. Riley, M.P. Hobson and S.J Bence. Chapters 14 to 18 details most of the methods required as well as special functions (such as the Hermite, associated Legendre, Laguerre polynomials etc.) encountered in physics. You should be able to find a pdf copy of it online with a simple google search.

Comment: Couldn't you still try rewriting it as first order system? Setting $z:=y'$ should give $y' = z, z' = \sqrt{-\frac CA - \frac BA y}$. Of course, this only works reasonably if $A$ stays away from zero uniformly.

Comment: @thedilated I am familiar with the book, but the problem in this case as you can see is the power in the $y''(x)$ term.

Comment: @DominikS, I thought about it, but since A, B and C are also dependent on variable $x$, I was a little confused about it.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what inflation model does this come from?

Comment: @Winther Galileon inflation! See here https://arxiv.org/abs/1008.0603

Comment: Where do you get $f''(x)^2$ from (assuming this is $\ddot{\phi}^2$)? If I remember correctly (but it's a long time since I looked at this) Galileons in general give equations of motion on the form $\ddot{\phi} F(\dot{\phi},\phi,t) = G(\dot{\phi},\phi,t)$.

Comment: In eq.(7) of the article I mentioned, the term $G_{X \phi}\ddot{\phi}$ can give rise to $\ddot{\phi}$ term!

Comment: But $G_{X\phi} \equiv \frac{d^2G(X,\phi)}{dXd\phi}$ is a function only of $X \sim \dot{\phi}^2$ and $\phi$ so I don't see why you should get a $\ddot{\phi}^2$ here. If I was you I would double check that this is really the equation you get (it might be, but I just don't see it).

Comment: You made me a little suspicious! I will recheck my whole calculation and let you know.

Comment: @Winther, You are right... There won't be the power term, which will make of equation simpler. Thanks for pointing out the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But, the way we solve 2nd order differential equation is not applicable here, i.e., writing it as two first order differential equations.

Why not?  Let $z = y'$;  then we have
$$
y'(x) = z(x) \\
z'(x) = \pm \sqrt{- \frac{B(x) y(x) + C(x)}{A(x)}} \\
z(0) = a \\
y(0) = b
$$
This will provide you with a local solution for $y(x)$ so long as $y''(x)$ does not cross zero (i.e., $z'(x)$ never switches sign.)  In fact, the solution in a neighborhood of 0 will not be unique (if it exists—the quantity under the square root could be negative);  there will be two solutions, one with $z'(0) > 0$ and one with $z'(0) < 0$.

Comment: Thank you for the insight... I will try now to implement it numerically.

Answer (score -1):

I would try using the Laplace Transform, isolate the function and then apply the inverse transform.

Comment: That's probably not going to work with a non-linear equation.